# How to make the execution time O(N) from O(N^2)

Tags: optimization

I tried to solve one programming problem(neither my homework nor any of my interview/test, but can be a good candidate) online.
The problem is given below. My code below functionally is correct, but it is of run-time complexity O(N<sup>2</sup>), where as solution expected should be in O(N).

I tried couple of other approaches to get it optimize - 1)Sorted the array and then tried if I could get this working, but since sorting causes indexes of the original numbers to be lost, i even kept those in a separate array, and did sovle it but even that ended up being O(N<sup>2</sup>). I am sure sorting of the array would help here to get to O(N) but just not been able to nail it.

Any help in getting this problem done in O(N) using any approach would be useful.

(Apologies for long post)

Consider a zero-indexed array A of N integers. Indices of this array are integers from 0 to N−1. Take an index K. Index J is called an ascender of K if A[J] > A[K]. Note that if A[K] is a maximal value in the array A, then K has no ascenders.

Ascender J of K is called the closest ascender of K if abs(K−J) is the smallest possible value (that is, if the distance between J and K is minimal). Note that K can have at most two closest ascenders: one smaller and one larger than K.

For example, let us consider the following array A:

A[0] = 4 A[1] = 3 A[2] = 1 A[3] = 4 A[4] = -1 A[5] = 2 A[6] = 1 A[7] = 5 A[8] = 7

If K = 3 then K has two ascenders: 7 and 8. Its closest ascender is 7 and distance between K and 7 equals abs(K−7) = 4.

Write a function:

```
struct Results {
  int * R;
  int N;
};

struct Results array_closest_ascenders(int A[], int N);
```

that, given a zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns a zero-indexed array R of N integers, such that (for K = 0,..., N−1):

```
    if K has the closest ascender J, then R[K] = abs(K−J); that is, R[K] is equal to the distance between J and K,
    if K has no ascenders then R[K] = 0.
```

For example, given the following array A:

A[0] = 4 A[1] = 3 A[2] = 1 A[3] = 4 A[4] = -1 A[5] = 2 A[6] = 1 A[7] = 5 A[8] = 7

the function should return the following array R:

R[0] = 7 R[1] = 1 R[2] = 1 R[3] = 4 R[4] = 1 R[5] = 2 R[6] = 1 R[7] = 1 R[8] = 0

Array R should be returned as:

```
    a structure Results (in C), or
    a vector of integers (in C++), or
    a record Results (in Pascal), or
    an array of integers (in any other programming language).
```

Assume that:

```
    N is an integer within the range [0..50,000];
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000,000..1,000,000,000].
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**My solution (O(N<sup>2</sup>)):**

```
#include <math.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct Results
{
    int *R;
    int N;
};

struct Results array_closest_ascenders ( int A[], int N )
{
    struct Results result;


     int i,j,asc_found=0;

     result.R = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);

     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
       result.R[i] = N;

     result.N = N;

     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
       asc_found = 0;
       for(j=0;j<N;j++)
       {
         if(A[i] < A[j])
         {
           //if(result.R[i] == 0)
           {
               if(result.R[i] > abs(i-j))
               {
                    result.R[i] = abs(i-j);
                    asc_found = 1;
               }
           }
         }
       }
       if(asc_found == 0)
           result.R[i] = 0;
     }


    return result;
}

void main()
{

    //int A[] = {4, 3, 1, 4, -1, 2, 1, 5, 7};
    int A[] = {691446939, -241956306, 485954938, 604054438, 383714185, -656099986, -357341170, -255988102, -139683363, -463281394, -382925609, 712727854};
    struct Results tmp;

    tmp = array_closest_ascenders(A,sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `N` be the index to search for ascendants near? not the # of elements in the array?

Comment: @Yochai - You got it wrong. The values in R[] should be the smallest possible value of the current index minus that index whose value is greater than its value(that is, index between current value and its ascendor should be minimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Left closest ascender* and *right closest ascender* can be considered separately. We go through the array once, computing left closest ascenders; and once again in the opposite direction, computing right closest ascenders. The closest ascender is the closer of the two.

In the algo below only left ascenders are considered. A stack of indices keeps track of left ascenders (all of them) of the current element. The closest ascender is always at the top of the stack.

```
for i in 0 .. N
  while (!stack.empty) && (A[stack.top] <= A[i])
    stack.pop
  if stack.empty
    then R[i] = 0
    else R[i] = i - stack.top
  stack.push(i)
```

Comment: Isn't this soln O(N^2) too? for{ while{} }

Comment: No. Each element is pushed once, and popped once.

Answer (score 0):

I mean to add this as a comment but no comment link is showing. Shouldn't R[] be following?

```
R[0]=abs(0-7)=7;
R[1]=abs(1-0)=1;
R[2]=abs(2-5)=3;
R[3]=abs(3-7)=4;
R[4]=abs(4-2)=2;/or 4-6
R[5]=abs(5-1)=4;
R[6]=abs(6-5)=1;
R[7]=abs(7-8)=1;
R[8]=abs(8-8)=0;
```

Based on your comment below, here is a program that works. The algorithm is based on counting sort (as presented on http://geekviewpoint.com/Sort_Algorithms_in_java/). The "offset" is to allow for negative values like "-1"

NOTE: although there is a nested loop for filling up R[], the algorithm is not N^2 because the second loop is iterating on the number of buckets.

ANSWER: [7, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ascender {
public static int[] ascenderArray(int[] A) {
    int max = A[0], min = A[0];
    for (int i : A) {
        if (max < i)
            max = i;
        if (min > i)
            min = i;
    }
    int offset = min < 0 ? -min : 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> buckets[] = new ArrayList[max + 1 + offset];
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
        buckets[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        buckets[A[i] + offset].add(i);

    int[] R = new int[A.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < R.length; i++) {
        try {
            min = A.length;
            int x = A[i] + 1 + offset;
            for (int n = x; n < buckets.length; n++) {
                x=n;
                while (buckets[x].isEmpty())
                    x++;
                n=x;
                int tmp = Math.abs(i - buckets[n].get(0));
                if (min > tmp)
                    min = tmp;
            }
            R[i] = min==A.length?0:min;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            R[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return R;
}//

public static void main(String... args) {
    int A[] = { 4, 3, 1, 4, -1, 2, 1, 5, 7 };
    int R[] = ascenderArray(A);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(R));
}
}
```

Comment: No. For K=2, i.e., A[2] = 1; J=1, A[1] = 3, is an ascender, abs(K-J) = abs(2-1) = 1.

Comment: Quote: "N is an integer within the range [0..50,000]; each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000,000..1,000,000,000]". How many buckets are there?

Comment: @goldenmean is there a reason you have not accepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if there is a Ο(*N*) solution, but here is a Ο(*N*·log *N*) solution in JavaScript:

```
var A = [4,3,1,4,-1,2,1,5,7],
    N = A.length;

// build an array of index:value pairs and sort them in ascending order
var sorted = [];
for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {
    sorted.push({index:i, value:A[i]});
}
sorted.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });

// iterate the sorted array in descending order
var ascenders = [],
    closest,            // closest ascender
    curr = sorted[N-1]; // initiate curr with largest item
ascenders[N-1] = 0;
for (var i=N-2; i>=0; i--) {
    // compare curr from the previous iteration with the future
    // curr of the current iteration
    if (sorted[i].value !== curr.value) {
        // update closest ascender if their values differ
        closest = curr;
    }
    curr = sorted[i];
    ascenders[i] = Math.abs(curr.index-closest.index);
}

// rearrange ascenders in the original order
var ret = [];
for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {
    ret[sorted[i].index] = ascenders[i];
}
```

Here sorting the values is the largest effort of Ο(*N*·log *N*).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class AsenderUtil {

    public static int[] getClosestAsenderIndices(int[] arr, int indx) {

        if (indx < 0 || arr.length <= indx)
            throw new RuntimeException("wrong input");

        int baseVal = arr[indx];

        TreeMap<Integer,Integer> ts = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]>baseVal) {
                ts.put(Math.abs(i-indx),i);
            }
        }

        int[] toReturn = new int[2];
        toReturn[0] = ts.remove(ts.firstKey());
        toReturn[1] = ts.remove(ts.firstKey());

        return toReturn;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int A[] = { 4, 3, 1, 4, -1, 2, 1, 5, 7 };
        int R[] = getClosestAsenderIndices(A,3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(R));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] A = new int[] { 4, 3, 1, 4, -1, 2, 1, 5, 7 };
         int[] B = new int[A.Length];
        int[] R = new int[A.Length];
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.ABC(A,B, R);
    }

    public void ABC(int[] A,int[]B, int[] R)
    {
        int i, j, m,k;
        // int temp = 0;
        int n = A.Length - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (A[i] < A[j])
                {
                    m = Math.Abs(j - i);
                    R[i] = m;
                    break;

                }

            }
            for (j = i-1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                if (A[i] < A[j])
                {
                    k = Math.Abs(j - i);
                    B[i] = k;
                    break;

                }

            }

        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (R[i] > B[i] && (B[i] == 0))
            {

                R[i] = R[i];
                //Console.WriteLine(R[i]);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }

            else { R[i] = B[i]; }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: In above solution I have taken 2 arrays R,B which store the distance. whichever array has the least distance and doesnot contain a 0 is the taken as the answer.
array R[i] checks the next number in forward direction 
array B[i] checks the next number in backward direction
For given example {4,3,1,4,-1,2,1,5,7}
R[i] ={ 7,1,2,4,4,5,6,1,0}
B[i]= {0,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0}
we will choose the result as the number that is lower in either of them( shortest distance) given that for the ith position the number in the other array should not be 0(zero)

our result will be {7,1,1,4,1,2,1,1,0}

Answer (score 0):

My solution is O(N):

```
class ArrayClosestAscendent {
 public int[] solution(int[] A) {
     int i;
     int r[] = new int[A.length];
     for(i=0;i<A.length;i++){
         r[i] = search(A, i);
     }
     return r;
 }

public int search(int[] A, int i) {
    int j,k;
    j=i+1;
    k=i-1;
    int result = 0;
    if(j <= A.length-1 && (A[j]>A[i]))
            return Math.abs(j-i);
    j++;
     while(k>=0 || j < A.length){
         if(k >= 0 && A[k] > A[i]){
             return Math.abs(i-k);
         }else if(j < A.length && A[j] > A[i]){
             return Math.abs(i-j);
         }else{
             j++;
             k--;
         }
     }
     return result;
}    
}
```

Basically in the search function I compare the first element of the array with the one immediately right, if it's bigger this means it is the first closest ascendant. For the other elements I compare the one immediately at left and afterward the one immediately right his first right element. The first one which is bigger is the closest ascendant, and I keep iterate this way until I don't find an element bigger than one I am considering or I return 0.